# Compound index MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I used MongoDb server version: 4.2.0.
I have Compound index MongoDB:

```
db.fop.createIndex( { "id":1, "ADDRESS": "text"})
```

It works:

```
db.fop.find({"id":{$in:[1]},$text: {$search: "AnyTextSearch"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

This does not work:

```
db.fop.find({"id":{$in:[1,2]},$text: {$search: "AnyTextSearch"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

I get an error:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=osint.fopTree: $and\n    id $in [ 1.0 2.0 ]\n    TEXT : query=AnyTextSearch, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: { score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } }\nProj: { score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } }\n planner returned error :: caused by :: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"}
```

How to make the right request?

Comment: Please tell what it means by "It works" and "This does not work".

Comment: Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=osint.fopTree: $and\n    id $in [ 1.0 2.0 ]\n    TEXT : query=AnyTextSearch, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL\nSort: { score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } }\nProj: { score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } }\n planner returned error :: caused by :: failed to use text index to satisfy $text query (if text index is compound, are equality predicates given for all prefix fields?)",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}

Comment: Here is the explanation: [text index restrictions when used with compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html#compound-index). The second point is the reason: _"If the compound text index includes keys preceding the text index key, to perform a $text search, the query predicate must include equality match conditions on the preceding keys."_

Comment: @prasad_ But it does include equality match conditions on the preceding keys. Seems a `$in` should work with two values if it works with one.

Comment: Can I use the $or ?

Comment: I guess it is a limitation and they really do need you to only use a single equality match. Does `$or` (on the top-level) work? How many ids do you have? This won't scale to very many.

Comment: @Thilo May be that the `$in` when used with _single array element_ is considered as _equality_ find. And, when used with more than one array element considered as using with the condition _or_.

Comment: Help me please. How to solve the goal?
**1)** I am find for string in text index.
**2)** I save id array.
**3)** I am find for new string in previously found documents. I try use id array and text index. 
`db.fop.find({"id":{$in:[1,2]},$text: {$search: "AnyTextSearch"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})` Do you have any idea how to do this?